# PHP: Regroup XML attributes

Tags: php, xml

I'm tried to parse XML response with DOM.

```
<GetBilletResult>
    <sNomProduit>product 2</sNomProduit>
    <sNomArticle>article 4</sNomArticle>
    ...
    <tabGrilleHoraire>
        <tabDetailTarifArticle>
            <tabDetail>
              <sDetail>Liste Pax : Pax n°1 [Âge:19]</sDetail>
              <sAgePax>19;</sAgePax>
              ...
            </tabDetail>
        </tabDetailTarifArticle>
        ...
    <tabGrilleHoraire>
</GetBilletResult>
```

I need to reorder the result and regroup the articles by products. The output should look like this :

- sNomProduit : product 2
- sNomArticle : article 1
- tabGrilleHoraire

  - tabDetailTarifArticle

    - tabDetail

      - sDetail : Liste Pax : Pax n°1 [Âge:19]
      - sAgePax : 19;

**Working code (thanks to ConstantineUA)** :

```
$processed = array();
foreach( $billets as $GetBilletResult )
{ 
$sNomProduit = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "sNomProduit" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$nIDProduit = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "nIDProduit" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$sNomArticle = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "sNomArticle" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$nIDArticle = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "nIDArticle" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$tabDetail = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "tabDetail" );

if (!isset($processed[$sNomProduit])) {
     $processed[$sNomProduit] = array();
}

$processed[$sNomProduit][] = array(
     'nIDProduit' => $nIDProduit,
     'sNomArticle' => $sNomArticle,
     'nIDArticle' => $nIDArticle,
     'tabDetail' => $tabDetail,
);
}
```

Loop:

```
foreach ($processed as $sNomProduit => $list) {
    echo "<h3> ".$sNomProduit."</h3>";
    foreach ($list as $item) {
        echo "<h5> ".$item['sNomArticle'] . "</h5>";
        foreach ($item['tabDetail'] as $node) {
            var_dump ($node->nodeValue);
        }
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get by with an additional associative array where you put all you nodes during the loop:

```
$processed = array();
foreach( $billets as $GetBilletResult )
{ 
    $sNomProduit = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "sNomProduit" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $nIDProduit = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "nIDProduit" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $sNomArticle = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "sNomArticle" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $nIDArticle = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "nIDArticle" )->item(0)->nodeValue;

    if (!isset($processed[$sNomProduit])) {
         $processed[$sNomProduit] = array();
    }

    $processed[$sNomProduit][] = array(
         'nIDProduit' => $nIDProduit,
         'sNomArticle' => $sNomArticle,
         'nIDArticle' => $nIDArticle,
    );
}
```

And then loop through this array to display results:

```
foreach ($processed as $sNomProduit => $list) {
    echo "<b>sNomProduit : </b> ".$sNomProduit."<br>";
    foreach ($list as $item) {
        echo "<b>sNomArticle : </b> ".$item['sNomArticle'] . "<br>";
        echo "<b>ListeTranche </b> ID_Tranche ".$item['nIDArticle'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

It looks that your xml isn't complete so please note that it's more like a pseudo-code rather than a complete solution.

Comment: I got this : **Notice: Undefined index: TEST - POUR LA RESA - PORTAVENTURA in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.php on line 284** _(same for th other results)_
`sNomProduit : TEST - POUR LA RESA - PORTAVENTURA
sNomProduit : TEST - POUR LA RESA - EUROPA-PARK 1 JOUR
sNomProduit : TEST - POUR LA RESA - EUROPA-PARK 2 JOURS
sNomProduit : TEST 1
...
sNomProduit : PRODUIT A
sNomProduit : PRODUIT B
sNomProduit : PRODUIT C
sNomProduit : COPIE -4- : PRODUIT A`

Comment: my bad, I slightly edited answer, please pay attention to lines where the new array key is initialized: 

if (!isset($processed[$sNomProduit])) {
    $processed[$sNomProduit] = array();
}

Comment: Nice, no errors. Now i need to show articles by product. `foreach ($processed as $sNomProduit => $list) {
    echo "<b>sNomProduit : </b> ".$sNomProduit."<br>";
    foreach ($list as $item) {
    // here goes further output
 echo "****** <b>sNomArticle : </b> ".$sNomArticle."<br>";
    }
}` this code show the same article _sNomProduit : TEST - POUR LA RESA - EUROPA-PARK 1 JOUR
****** sNomArticle : ARTICLE A2
sNomProduit : TEST - POUR LA RESA - EUROPA-PARK 2 JOURS
****** sNomArticle : ARTICLE A2
sNomProduit : TEST 1
****** sNomArticle : ARTICLE A2_

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it, do you mean you have duplicate articles in the response, Could you please share an actual xml file with response?

Comment: I've updated the answer a bit, namely expanded output of sub-items in the second loop. As on the previous step we put some data into the array of processed data, now we can reference them during the render. By the way there is a few notices while processing your xml as GetBilletResult may be empty, I see such items in the xml: <GetBilletResult>...</GetBilletResult>. At the same time you code doesn't handle this situation.

Comment: Nice ! Just one more thing, how can i read "sEtatArt" value (third level) ?

Comment: well, it's the same as reading other attributes like 'sNomArticle' or 'sNomProduit', just fetch them with getElementsByTagName function as it looks all the child elements up to leafs of xml-tree. Level of nesting doesn't matter.

Comment: Question updated. I'm trying to add `tabGrilleHoraire => tabDetailTarifArticle => tabDetail` array to the result. But `var_dump($item['tabDetailTarifArticle']) ;` return a string not array :(

Comment: Any help please ?  @ConstantineUA

Comment: Sorry, I'll have a look later

Comment: This is a code sample : [link](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/456879screenshot20160810.png) @ConstantineUA

Comment: I am really stuck here :'(

Comment: Please have a look at line 61 from your code sample, the problem is that you're restricting list of 'tabDetailTarifArticle' of items to first item, instead you have to fetch all: $tabDetailTarifArticle = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "tabDetailTarifArticle" );

Comment: Code updated : [link](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/639754screenshot201608104.png) this the array structure [link](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/547375screenshot201608103.png)

Comment: Any idea how to display "tabDetail" array at once ?

Comment: I guess loop through you tabDetail array and display whatever is necessary

Comment: Done, but i don't know why the arrays under "tabDetail" array are displayed as strings ([actual code](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/639754screenshot201608104.png), [tabDetail array structure](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/547375screenshot201608103.png)) ...